# Link follows when using UIWebView+AFNetworking

Tags: ios, uiwebview, afnetworking-2

I'm trying out AFNetworking 2.0+'s new `UIKit+AFNetworking` extension for `UIWebView`, `loadRequest:progress:success:failure:`. So far so good, but after the initial request is made, additional requests caused by user interaction falls back to the built-in `loadRequest:` of plain `UIWebView`.

I'd much prefer that all requests went through the `AFNetworking` improved one. Preliminary, I'm thinking I should override as much as possible by returning `NO` in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` and call `loadRequest:progress:success:failure:` manually, but it seems a little heavy-handed.

Is this the intended way or am I missing something in the documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be worth reading through the [implementation of UIWebView+AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit+AFNetworking/UIWebView+AFNetworking.m) (it's only 120 lines).

What you're looking for isn't implemented by this class.  Furthermore, since `UIWebView+AFNetworking` is a category, which extends an existing object, implementing it in this class would require setting the UIWebView's delegate to itself, which would stop you from responding to any of its delegate methods.

Your discussed possible approach - returning `NO` to `-[id<UIWebViewDelegate>  webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:]` and then redirecting to use the method you want is the right approach.  (You'll need to return `YES` for your own request.)