# UIWebView+AFNetworking: Back/Forward Broken

Tags: ios, uiwebview, afnetworking

After loading a web page using AFNetworking's `loadRequest:progress:success:failure:` method, my UIWebView's back/forward navigation and properties are broken. AFNetworking's docs mention needing to implement `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method and I have, always returning YES. Is there are particular implementation I need for the back/forward functionality to remain intact?

Also, I'd like to have all loads to this web view go through AFNetworking so I can get the progress updates. I've heard you can override the previously mentioned delegate method to accomplish this but I can't see a way to reject native requests and funnel everything through AFNetworking.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384418/link-follows-when-using-uiwebviewafnetworking

Comment: I'm familiar with that question, as that's where I heard about overriding the delegate method. Unfortunately it didn't offer an details about how to do that. Also, from what I've read, AFNetworking's category should leave the back/forward functionality intact, unless I'm missing something.